# Location Modifiers gets lost after exporting to collada

Tags: modifiers, rigging, collada

I'm trying to import an 3D-Model which I have created with blender.
My goal is to resize the 3D Frame accordingly programmatically with the help of an armature. 
I could achieve this within blender but unfortunately when importing the .dae file in Xcode it looks like one location modifier was not applied...

Underneath the described behavior:

BLENDER

[image]

XCODE

[image]

Is my armature wrong assembled or does anyone has a better solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance!!!